# Enable text-box according to a combo-box select

Tags: html, angular

I'd like to Enable/Disable a textbox according to a combo-box select... If `value=""` is selected, I want the *Content* text-box to be disabled. I've tried a lot of things, but nothing worked... 
Any idea if how I can solve this issue?

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="formulario">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="SearchField">Field:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <select formControlName="SearchField" class="form-control" (change)="choice(searchField.value)" #searchField>
          <option value="" selected disabled>Pick a Choice</option>
          <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
          <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
          <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
          <option value="4">Choice 4</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="ContentField">Content:&nbsp;</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ContentField" [textMask]="mask" [(ngModel)]="search" placeholder="{{ this.searchKind }}" #docField />
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix ReactiveForm and template-drive forms --> bad idea.
With ReactiveForms you must use disable() and enable() methods.

your component.html must be like

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="formulario">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="SearchField">Field:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <select formControlName="SearchField" class="form-control" (change)="choice(formulario.controls['SearchField'].value)" #searchField >
        <option value="" selected>Pick a Choice</option>
        <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
        <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
        <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
        <option value="4">Choice 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="ContentField">Content:&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ContentField"  #docField />
        </div>
  </div>
```

Take a look as we ommited "ngmodels" and how call to choice(formulario.controls['SearchField'].value)

Your component must be like

```
....
ngOnInit() {
   this.formulario = this.fb.group({
      SearchField:null,
      ContentField: [{value:null,disabled:true}] //at first is disabled
   });
}
choice(value:any)
{
   //use diabled() and enabled()
   if (!value)
      this.formulario.controls['ContentField'].disable();
   else
      this.formulario.controls['ContentField'].enable();
}
```

Take a look when how we make disabled at first.

Or you can use a directive like show in [netbasal's blog](https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110)

```
 //Directive from https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective {
  @Input() set disableControl( condition : boolean ) {
    if (condition)
        this.ngControl.disable();
    else
        this.ngControl.enable();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl ) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-model for this

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="formulario">
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="SearchField">Field:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <select formControlName="SearchField" class="form-control" (change)="choice(searchField.value)" #searchField ng-model="selectVal">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Pick a Choice</option>
      <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
      <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
      <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
      <option value="4">Choice 4</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="ContentField">Content:&nbsp;</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disabled="selectVal==''" formControlName="ContentField" [textMask]="mask" [(ngModel)]="search" placeholder="{{ this.searchKind }}" #docField />
      </div>
</div>
```

Here you can assign a ng-model for drop down,and use ng-disabled in your textbox.
ng-disabled condition should be the value which you want to make the action

Comment: Thanks!! but, it also didn't work...I think I'm forgetting something

Comment: Do I have to make any changes on Typescript?

Comment: The way you think is this, Above code update is for angular, in your case you have to catch the change event and the value, then you have to add disable option to text box related to the output value

Comment: <select [ngModel]="selectVal" (ngModelChange)="choice($event)" name="sel2">
</select>